# Read file while the file is constantly changing c#

Tags: c#, file-io, fileparsing, output-redirect

I've written a c# application which is supposed to open a selected file, and read all the lines in it.

The goal is to launch application `A` and redirect its output to file `B`, and then, using this new app, read the content of the file `B` and print it to a ListBox.

The thing is that application `A` is running 24/7 and writes new outputs to the file `B`, I would like to catch those new lines in real time, and print them to the ListBox.

Is that even possible? I tried using `File.ReadAllLines(filename)`, but that didn't work saying that the file is in use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759697/reading-a-file-used-by-another-process

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897796/how-do-i-open-an-already-opened-file-with-a-net-streamreader see the first answer

Comment: You could use the FileSystemWatcher to watch a directory for changes.

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229699/read-changes-on-a-text-file-dynamically-c-sharp

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate , this questions need more than that , he may need what to do after he knows the answer to the questions you guys provide as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this stream-reading solution?

```
     var reader = new System.IO.FileStream("Path", 
                                                 FileMode.Open, 
                                                 FileAccess.Read, 
                                                 FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa988006(v=vs.80).aspx 
This could resolve the problem of the "File is open".