# C# - Stream File to WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a log file on my machine that is getting written to by another application. The log file contains only text data.

I would like to show the contents of the log file in my WPF application. Typically, I would just use a `TextBox`. However, as the log file is being written to, I would like the content shown in the WPF app to get updated.

How do I "stream" content in a WPF app?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Changes on a text file dynamically c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229699/read-changes-on-a-text-file-dynamically-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) in your application that will tell you when the file has changed, a simple use case from the MS site is

```
public class Watcher
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            watcher.Path = args[1];

            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
            // the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnChanged;
            watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) =>
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e) =>
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.OldFullPath} renamed to {e.FullPath}");
}
```